# data is rendering on the html page but when applied styling bootstrap4 its not showing anything?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, materialize, angular8

[image]In my simple angular app, a  hard-coded data  is rendering in the webpage in simple formatting but when applied bootstrap style and classes it not showing anything. 
Please correct the below code if any:

This is event.component.html:

```
<div class="media">
  <h3 class="h3-responsive font-weight-bold mr-3">{{ value.time }}</h3>
  <div class="media-body mb-3 ">
    <mdb-badge danger="true" class="text-center float-right">-</mdb-badge>
    <h6 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold">{{ value.subject }}</h6>
    <hr class="hr-bold mb-0 my-2" />
    <p class="mb-0" *ngIf="value.location">
      <mdb-icon fas icon="location-arrow"></mdb-icon>
      {{ value.location }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="p-3 blue-grey lighten-5 blue-grey lighten-5" *ngIf="value.description">
  {{ value.description }}
</p>
```

this is  app.component.html:

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div *ngFor="let event of events">
            <app-event [value]="event"></app-event>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found out:

```
<div class="media">
  <h3 class="h3-responsive font-weight-bold mr-3">{{ value.time }}</h3>
  <div class="media-body mb-3">
    <span class="badge badge-danger text-center float-right">-</span>
    <h6 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold">{{ value.subject }}</h6>

    <p class="mb-0">
      <i class="fa fa-location-arrow solid" style="font-size:14px;"></i>  {{ value.location }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="p-3 " style="background-color: #D8D8D8;">
  {{ value.description }}
</p>
```

some of the classes in there were not from bootstrap but dont know where theey have brought form and how is that produced output in a blog . I tried much and found it!!